# How to decrease latency when getting product.metafields through the shopify Ruby gem?

Tags: ruby, shopify

Consider the following lines that interacts with the `shopify` Ruby gem.

First we fetch a bunch of products through Shopify's REST API.

```rb
products = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(:all, :params => {})
product  = products.first
```

Then we try getting the metafields of a product.

```rb
puts Benchmark.measure { 100.times { |s| product.metafields } }
# => 0.375952   0.083343   0.459295 ( 26.157793)
```

Any idea why getting metafields takes this long time? As far as I understand they are part of the product object and does not require a separate API request.

Comment: _"As far as I understand they are part of the product object [...]"_ – from the docs it looks like metafields are custom resources that have to be fetched separately: https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-rest/2023-10/resources/metafield

Comment: Seems you are correct. And I don't see a way to request metafields from multiple owners in a single request, do you agree? Meaning that getting metafields from 100 products would require 100 requests.

Comment: You can [Retrieve a list of metafields by using query parameters](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-rest/2023-10/resources/metafield#get-metafields?metafield[owner-id]=382285388&metafield[owner-resource]=blog) although I'm not sure if you can pass multiple ids.

Comment: Just tried it out passing multiple ids separated by comma, but the API returns "expected String to be a id". So probably I'm out of luck.

Comment: Maybe you can utilize the GraphQL API to build a custom query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget using Rest API for this. Instead, switch to GraphQL. Like magic, your product query can now ask for and extract metafields. Wonderful! What progress! Use RestAPI only when you need basic information not otherwise serviced by GraphQL as they are not at parity.